# Store customer information without charge in Authorize.net and Accept.js?

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

I'm using Authorize.net and have spent a couple days reviewing the documentation but for the life of me, I can't seem to figure out a way to store credit card information of a customer without the card hitting our server.

In the [Accept.js documentation](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html) it appears that they grant a nonce that's available for 15 minutes but I don't see a way to use that nonce just to store the card. Is there any way to use their JS library for creating a customer?

This seems like something that should be so basic but for whatever reason, I can't find it.

Comment: Did you find any answer to this? I would also like to know how to create a CIM customer profile and CIM customer payment profile using **my own form** rather than Authorize.net's hosted forms. I see nothing in the [accept.js](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html) docs that gets close to showing how this is done.

Comment: The documentation linked in this question has everything needed to answer this question. (Perhaps the docs have been updated since 2017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nonce or one-time token can be used to create a customer profile by replacing the payment object from specifying card data to use the nonce:

When using [createCustomerProfileRequest](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-create-customer-profile), change the payment object from specifying card data as below:

```
 <payment>
      <creditCard>
        <cardNumber>4111111111111111</cardNumber>
        <expirationDate>2020-12</expirationDate>
      </creditCard>
 </payment>
```

and change the payment object to use the nonce:

```
  <payment>
     <opaqueData>
        <dataDescriptor>COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT</dataDescriptor>
        <dataValue>nonce_here</dataValue >
     </opaqueData>
  </payment>
```

Comment: This answer is very confusing. the XML markup you describe seems to have no relation at all to the [accept.js library](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html). The original poster here is asking how to create a customer payment profile using a Javascript library and your response refers confusingly to some XML with no mention of the Javascript necessary to create a CIM profile from the supplied card data.

Comment: @S.Imp As I understand it, the Accept.js library returns a nonce. This nonce can then be used for various things. One of those things is to create a CIM profile via a *server side* API. We currently use a PHP SDK to create CIM profiles and are looking into (as described in this answer) is using an Accept.js nonce (`opaqueData`) instead of actual credit card data. The Accept.js library generates the nonce, the XML shown here is used with the Authorize.net API to create the CIM profile.

Comment: For more info, see [Using the Payment Nonce in an API Request From Your Server](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html#Using_the_Payment_Nonce_in_an_API_Request_From_Your_Server)

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.net states you can use a Nonce from access.js anywhere you can use Bank info or Credit Card info. But the documentation is pretty unclear.

Took me a minute to find it but you are using one of the SDKs then you can look in the repos for examples on how to to create the opaqueData object and pass it into the payment object.

[Python example of creating a payment transaction with a nonce](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-python/blob/9eccda3fa4205ef005ab8119ad63f0cb90171c08/PaymentTransactions/create-an-accept-payment-transaction.py)

Use Access.js to capture the Opaque object, (the return value on success) then pass it to the server, it contains the dataValue (nonce) and the dataDescriptor. Then follow the sample projects example on how to create a payment profile, but replace the payment info with the following.

```
# PYTHON EXAMPLE

opaqueData = apicontractsv1.opaqueDataType()
opaqueData.dataDescriptor = "COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT"

# This is the nonce you get back from the server. This particular one 
# is from the example I linked above but shortened to fit the width of 
# this view.
opaqueData.dataValue = "119eyJjb2RlIjoiNTBfMl8wNjAwMDUyN0J..."

# Add the payment data to a paymentType object
payment = apicontractsv1.paymentType()
payment.opaqueData = opaqueData

# Now you can use this payment object anywhere you'd use the typical 
# creditcard or bankinfo payment objects. Including creating payment profiles.
```